# How to avoid recycling when using roll_mean in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have been trying to apply a rolling mean to several columns in a dataframe, where each column contains data from multiple individuals.  I have succeeded using roll_mean from the RcppRoll package and lapply.  I've included below an example using a dummy dataframe and the output.

```
    x <- rnorm(20,1);
    y <- rnorm(20,2);
    z <- rnorm(20,3);
    ID <- rep(1:2, each=10);

    mydf <- data.frame(ID, x, y, z);

    vars <- c("x", "y", "z");

setDT(mydf)[, paste0(vars, "_", "mean") := lapply(.SD, function(x) roll_mean(x, n=3, na.rm = TRUE)), .SDcols = vars, by = ID]

mydf

        ID           x          y         z    x_mean    y_mean   z_mean
     1:  1  0.34457704  1.9580361 2.6458335 1.2515642 1.8307447 2.569645
     2:  1  1.41839352  2.0697324 1.8495358 1.7012511 1.7248261 2.988908
     3:  1  1.99172192  1.4644657 3.2135652 1.8455087 1.7165419 3.184736
     4:  1  1.69363783  1.6402801 3.9036227 1.5002658 2.1512764 3.289555
     5:  1  1.85116646  2.0448798 2.4370206 0.9775842 3.1215589 2.563110
     6:  1  0.95599300  2.7686692 3.5280206 0.8477701 3.4576141 3.106095
     7:  1  0.12559300  4.5511275 1.7242892 0.9450234 3.5134499 3.020176
     8:  1  1.46172438  3.0530454 4.0659766 0.9080677 3.0100022 3.371839
     9:  1  1.24775283  2.9361768 3.2702614 1.2515642 1.8307447 2.569645
    10:  1  0.01472603  3.0407845 2.7792776 1.7012511 1.7248261 2.988908
    11:  2 -0.91146047  2.5898074 2.0328348 0.4314443 1.2688530 2.477879
    12:  2  0.48183559  1.8230335 2.6910075 1.2689767 0.9650435 2.544006
    13:  2  1.72395769 -0.6062819 2.7097949 0.8747931 1.2273766 1.974265
    14:  2  1.60113680  1.6783790 2.2312143 0.2579207 1.6945497 2.233321
    15:  2 -0.70071522  2.6100328 0.9817857 0.1162224 2.0928536 2.606608
    16:  2 -0.12665946  0.7952374 3.4869635 1.3884888 2.1063817 2.986786
    17:  2  1.17604187  2.8732906 3.3510742 2.0557599 2.2701173 3.178248
    18:  2  3.11608400  2.6506171 2.1223190 1.5553274 2.3987061 3.015501
    19:  2  1.87515393  1.2864441 4.0613513 0.4314443 1.2688530 2.477879
    20:  2 -0.32525560  3.2590570 2.8628313 1.2689767 0.9650435 2.544006
```

As you can see from the output table (mydf) the mean parameters have been created as part of the lapply statement, and the rolling means have been calculated for each individual ID.  However, the rolling mean function has recycled the results in order to fill the data frame, as the roll_mean function generates 8 values from the 10 raw values for each individual ID.  It has used recycling to fill the last 2 rows for each ID.
My actual data is time series data and I don't want the results recycled.  I want to avoid recycling by adding the raw x values to the start of the x_mean column up until the point where there are sufficient raw data to produce the 3 point rolling mean.

I've tried searching (on SO and google) for posts about avoiding recycling in roll_mean or similar functions with no success.

Does anyone know how to pad the first 2 rows in my example to avoid recycling in the roll_mean function?

Thanks.

Comment: `RcppRoll::roll_mean()` should have a `fill` argument, just use `NA` there and later copy the values from `x`, `y`, and `z` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole solution:

```
x <- rnorm(20,1);
y <- rnorm(20,2);
z <- rnorm(20,3);
ID <- rep(1:2, each=10);

mydf <- data.table(ID, x, y, z);  # Changed to dt here

vars <- c("x", "y", "z");

# fill = NA and align = 'right'
mydf[, paste0(vars, "_", "mean") := lapply(.SD, function(x) RcppRoll::roll_mean(x, n = 3, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA, align = 'right')), .SDcols = vars, by = ID]

mydf

#     ID          x         y        z    x_mean   y_mean   z_mean
#  1:  1  0.3735462 2.9189774 2.835476        NA       NA       NA
#  2:  1  1.1836433 2.7821363 2.746638        NA       NA       NA
#  3:  1  0.1643714 2.0745650 3.696963 0.5738536 2.591893 3.093026
#  4:  1  2.5952808 0.0106483 3.556663 1.3144318 1.622450 3.333422
#  5:  1  1.3295078 2.6198257 2.311244 1.3630533 1.568346 3.188290
# ...

mydf[is.na(x_mean), c(paste0(vars, "_", "mean")) := mget(paste0(vars))]

mydf

#     ID          x         y        z    x_mean   y_mean   z_mean
#  1:  1  0.3735462 2.9189774 2.835476 0.3735462 2.918977 2.835476
#  2:  1  1.1836433 2.7821363 2.746638 1.1836433 2.782136 2.746638
#  3:  1  0.1643714 2.0745650 3.696963 0.5738536 2.591893 3.093026
#  4:  1  2.5952808 0.0106483 3.556663 1.3144318 1.622450 3.333422
#  5:  1  1.3295078 2.6198257 2.311244 1.3630533 1.568346 3.188290
# ...
```

**Edit:**

Missing parts of `mydf` can be also filled in a bit "smarter" way, i.e. by using roll means with window smaller by 1 in every iteration:

```
for (n_inner in n_roll:1) {
  mydf[!complete.cases(mydf),
       paste0(vars, "_", "mean") := lapply(
         .SD, function(x) RcppRoll::roll_mean(x, n = n_inner, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA, align = 'right')), .SDcols = vars, by = ID]
  }

#     ID          x         y        z    x_mean   y_mean   z_mean
#  1:  1  0.3735462 2.9189774 2.835476 0.3735462 2.918977 2.835476 <- Values from x, y and z
#  2:  1  1.1836433 2.7821363 2.746638 0.7785948 2.850557 2.791057 <- roll_mean with window 2
#  3:  1  0.1643714 2.0745650 3.696963 0.5738536 2.591893 3.093026 <- roll_mean with window 3
#  4:  1  2.5952808 0.0106483 3.556663 1.3144318 1.622450 3.333422 <- as above
#  5:  1  1.3295078 2.6198257 2.311244 1.3630533 1.568346 3.188290
# ...
```

Comment: To fill `NA`s also `mydf[!complete.cases(mydf), c(paste0(vars, "_", "mean")) := mget(paste0(vars))]` can be used.